# Why does Cryptbreaker need to specify "untapped" Zombies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Cryptbreaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCryptbreaker%5d) has the following ability:

> Tap three untapped Zombies you control: You draw a card and you lose 1 life.

Why is it necessary to specify that the three Zombies must be untapped? You can't tap an already tapped creature, or use tapped creatures to pay a tap cost. MtG cards usually have a very good economy of words, so why include this seemingly unnecessary text? Would the card function differently in any circumstance if it just said "Tap three Zombies you control"?

Comment: There are a couple instances of MTG using extra words simply for extra clarity. Such as when they added "base" to "base power and toughness".

Comment: And often using "when [card] or another creature enters the battlefield", even though "when a creature enters the battlefield" would work just the same.

Comment: @GendoIkari In that case, maybe the best answer is one that explains why the card would function the same way even if the word "untapped" was removed?

Comment: The CompRules are anything but economic. Not that I'm complaining, but you will often find the same rule, sometimes verbatim, in several different places, or the same basic rules such as APNAP in various wordings in different places.

Comment: @GendoIkari I don't think "base" is redundant. If the card text says 3/3, and it has a 1/1 counter, then its power is 4, but its base power is 3.

Comment: @Acccumulation "Base" was added in the context of cards of cards that set creatures' power and toughness such as [Humility](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4881). Adding "base" to the card did not change the functionality at all; previously setting a card to "1/1" would only affect the "base", but the word "base" didn't exist as part of Magic rules.

Comment: https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/magic-2015-update-bulletin-2014-07-17

Comment: @GendoIkari If you're saying that wording regarding *setting* base power is redundant, that's arguably true, but wording regarding *checking* base power is not.

Comment: @Acccumulation Is there anything in the game that checks base power? To my knowledge, the word "base" was specifically added in the context of setting power/toughness; I'm not aware of it ever being used in a different context.

Comment: Rule 208.4, which is where "base" is defined, says "Effects that set a creature’s power and/or toughness[...]". As far as I can tell, a rules update would be required to even allow a card to refer to "base power" in a different context.

Comment: In a [recent question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/42797/2880), someone asked why "*destroy one of those permanents at random*" forces one of the non-indestructible permanents to be destroyed. The OP effectively thought it meant "*choose one of those permanents at random, then destroy it*" (In reality, you must choose a legal option, even when choosing randomly.) The extra word avoids that confusion here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct that the word is unnecessary; it would function the same without.

There are various times that MTG adds extra words for the sake of clarity; even when they have no effect on functionality.

A very common example are cards such as [Aetherstorm Roc](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAetherstorm%20Roc%5d), which use the wording "Aetherstorm Roc or another creature enters the battlefield under your control..."

This could have simply been written "Whenever a creature enters the battlefield under your control" for the exact same effect. But there would be some less experienced players that would not know if it should count itself or not. The longer wording makes this explicit.

"Tap an untapped creature you control" works the same way. If it simply said "Tap a creature you control", then you wouldn't be able to activate it without actually tapping an untapped creature, due to the rule:

> 701.20a To tap a permanent, turn it sideways from an upright position. **Only untapped permanents can be tapped.**

However, the extra word helps make it clear that this is the case. Especially due to the fact that a "tap target creature" ability can in fact target a tapped creature, some people would wonder what stops them from choosing tapped creatures to pay the activation cost for "tap a creature you control".

Comment: I can think of a theoretical way that the 2 wordings for Aetherstorm Roc would function different; if a continuous effect were around that said that all creatures are not creatures. Then Roc would not trigger for itself under the shortened wording, but would still trigger for itself with the current wording. But that is an extreme case that I don't even know if it can exist with current cards.

Comment: @Gendolkari I'm pretty sure that Roc's ability would still work the same. The wording "Roc or *another* creature" implies that Roc has to be a creature to trigger its ability.

Comment: @Hackworth I'm almost sure that's not right; I remember other questions where similar things were discussed.

Comment: Could you dig that one up? Genuinely interested.

Comment: @Hackworth Couldn't find it... I do remember a question about the word "another" used in this way. A simpler example: You have 
Ivy Lane Denizen and Darkest Hour, making the Denizen black. You should still get the triggered ability whenever a green creature enters the battlefield, even though "another green creature" no longer makes sense.

Comment: Let's move it to chat

Comment: It may be worth noting that new players can be confused as untapped creatures may be untapped, so they may assume that tapped creatures can also be tapped.

Comment: Also, now that I think of it, you and other players may tap creatures (of you) that are tapped. You just cannot pay their tappings as a cost for spells and abilities. 
See? There is so much people can be confused about.

Comment: @SimonKlaver That is not correct. 701.20b: "Only tapped permanents can be untapped.".

Comment: @SimonKlaver No, that's not correct. 701.20a as quoted in my answer says otherwise.

Comment: You are probably thinking of the fact that a tapped creature is a legal target for an ability that says "tap target creature". The target is legal, but upon resolving, the ability will fail to do anything, because it is impossible to tap the tapped creature.

Comment: @GendoIkari I seem to be really bad at this. As you said, it is a legal target, but does not actually get tapped as that is not a legal effect. After trying to find confusing scenarios the only one confused is me! Gaaah!

Comment: @SimonKlaver I believe that your confusion is the primary reason that the extra wording is added on Cryptbreaker; which the other answer goes into more detail about. So I don't think you're alone!

Comment: @Hackworth, Re "*The wording "Roc or another creature" implies that Roc has to be a creature to trigger its ability.*", No. "another creature" means "a creature other than this object". There's no implied check.

Comment: @SimonKlaver, Re "*you and other players may tap creatures (of you) that are tapped*", That's not true. For example, if a card said "*Tap or untap target creature*", you would be force to toggle its status because you can't tap/untap a creature that tapped/untapped. That's why most abilities say "***You may** tap or untap target creature*" instead. [Example](https://magiccards.info/ori/en/212.html)

Comment: @ikegami Hackworth knows this, a back-and-forth in chat resulted in [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42947/does-card-name-or-another-type-require-card-name-to-be-in-the-proper-cat); which cleared it up.

Comment: @Gendolkari, Thanks, I missed that. ...Except I commented on an answer, so I guess just totally blanked it out.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I would say that it has to do with the fact that yes, you can't tap a tapped permanent **to pay a cost**, but if a spell or ability has an **effect** that taps a permanent, you can target a permanent that is already tapped, depending on the wording of the spell or ability.

A rule (I don't know which one, I'm not in a place where I can look up the number) says:

> If an effect attempts to do something impossible, it does only as much as possible.

For instance, Hands of Binding is a blue Sorcery that says:

> Tap target creature an opponent controls. That creature doesn't untap during its controller's next untap step.
>
> Cipher (Then you may exile this spell card encoded on a creature you control. Whenever that creature deals combat damage to a player, its controller may cast a copy of the encoded card without paying its mana cost.)

**Notice:** It does not say Tap target *untapped* creature an opponent controls.

Let's say that your opponent has two creatures, one of whom is tapped; you have one creature. You cast Hands of Binding on your opponent's untapped creature, then cipher it onto your creature. You attack and when it deals combat damage to the player, you get to recast Hands of Binding. You can target the other creature **even though it was already tapped**.

When you (re)cast Hands of Binding, the creature is a legal target, because the only requirement is that the target be a creature. When the spell resolves, the target is still valid (the spell checks for legality twice). So the effects start to happen.

The first one tries and fails to happen because, as has already been mentioned, you can't tap a tapped creature, so that effect fizzles.

**HOWEVER**

Then the second effect happens:

> That creature doesn't untap during its controller's next untap step.

That effect **can** happen, so it does. Presto! You now have two creatures that your opponent controls that won't untap during that player's next untap step.

I think that it's specifically this type of interaction that leads to the "extra* text on Cryptbreaker and other cards like it. Technically it's redundant, but it alleviates the confusion for people that are familiar with this interaction.